# getting a groupby error through a for loop

Tags: pandas-groupby

```
fashion = [1,1,2,3,3,3,21,1,1,1,5,5,5,5,3,3,2,6]  
for key,group in groupby(fashion):
print(key,':',list(group))
```

I have written the above code to group by certain numbers and get a list. For example, I want an outcome such as :

```
1 : [1,1,1,1,1]
2 : [2,2]
```

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

`fashion` is neither a sorted list for itertools.groupby() nor a Pandas DataFrame.  Please post the fully functioning code with clarification on if you are attempting to use Pandas for grouping a series or DataFrame.

[How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Contains good advices for getting help with Pandas features.